# How can I change the width of a tab using a keyboard shortcut in PhpStorm?

Tags: configuration, keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm

I am using JetBrains PhpStorm and want to setup a keyboard-only environment.

When I want to increase or decrease the width of the sidebar, I can use

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> (Increment Width Action)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> (Decrement Width Action)

Yet I also have multiple tabs open in vertical split. Here, the combination for the sidebar doesn't work, as it is used for text selection here.

How can I change the width of a currently active tab using the keyboard only.

Before:

[image]

After:
[image]

yet without using the mouse at all.

Comment: I don't understand which part of PHPStorm you want to change.is there a sidebar or a tab bar in top of editor ?

Comment: @darkomen Added picture.